# firebase app distribution on non google play services devices

Tags: android, firebase-app-distribution

I've installed firebase-app-distribution Tester App on Huawei P40 (no google play services). When i open app it offers to login, but after clicking on Sign in with Google nothing happens.

Does it mean that firebase-app-distribution works only on android devices with google play services?

When I install App Tester, open it and click "Sign In with Google" button, I see in logs:
**E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.**

And this line appears in log only after clicking "Sign in with Google" button in App Tester

Answer (score 0):

Chintan from Firebase DevRel. You do need Google Play Services for Sign in with Google on App Tester. As a work around, you can use the web tester experience on your Android Device instead of App Tester

Comment: Hi Chintan, can you share more about the web tester? like how to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the tester app inside the [GBox](https://gboxlab.com/) emulation;
while all devices would pretend to be the same device, for certain,
because it would install in the emulation, not the hardware device.